# CRON expression to schedule on hourly basis like e.g. 04:00, 10:00, 16:00, 22:00

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I tried with * 4,10,16,22 * * * but didnt worked out throwing error while parsing the CRON expression.

I'm using CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CRON_EXPRESSION) method to schedule the job.

Please let me know is there anyother way apart from scheduling separately.

Answer (score 1):

According to the below reference CronScheduleBuilder cant do that. Use the expression you wrote directly in the cron command without using CronScheduleBuilder.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/quartznet/P4m4X_uuhEM

See cron man page for details: http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/crontab/